# format the json data with jquery in to a particular format

Tags: jquery, json

I am trying to construct a pie chart with flot, and getting the json data from server as below

```
[
  {"transactions": 7, "products__name": "mark"}, 
  {"transactions": 12, "products__name": "vicky"}, 
  {"transactions": 30, "products__name": "daniel"},   
  {"transactions": 6, "products__name": "hurray "}]
```

So i need to format the above list of dictionaries in to below format so that i can use that to directly insert to `flot` pie chat `placeholder`

```
data = [
    { label: "mark",  data: 7, color: "#4572A7"},
    { label: "vicky",  data: 12, color: "#80699B"},
    { label: "daniel",  data: 30, color: "#3D96AE"},
    { label: "hurray",  data: 6, color: "#89A54E"},
];
```

Actually i just want to do this with `jquery`, by using `foreach` or something else..

Comment: Where did the color values come from? Are they randomly chosen?

Comment: I actually i want to add the color manually, so since i know there will be only 5 items in the list for sure, manually i want to assign color to each item in the list

Answer (score 3):

```
lst = [
  {"transactions": 7, "products__name": "mark"}, 
  {"transactions": 12, "products__name": "vicky"}, 
  {"transactions": 30, "products__name": "daniel"},   
  {"transactions": 6, "products__name": "hurray "}]
colors = ["#4572A7", "#80699B", "#3D96AE", "#89A54E"]
data = []

for i, c in zip(lst, colors):
   data.append({'label': i['products__name'], 'data': i["transactions"], 'color': c,})
```

Comment: sorry i want to do this with jquery, i will get only five items in the list, so i want to arrange the color fixed to the records

Comment: I added colour to them.

Comment: i just want to do this logic with jquery not python

Comment: Why you add `python` tag to your question?

Comment: I added python because, i am getting the data in python right

Comment: No, you are getting the data in JSON.

Comment: yeah, my intention is to say that i am using python and getting the json response from the server